# Optimize Postgres query - Bitmap heap scan seems slow

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm testing a query and wondering if performance can be improved.
There are 9 million records in this table. The database used is Postgres 12.
The query should be quick for any account, docket type, quantity.

```
SELECT d.docket_id, d.docket_type_id
FROM docket d
WHERE d.account_id = 557  AND (d.docket_type_id = ANY(array[2]))
AND exists (
 select 1
 from jsonb_array_elements(d.equipment) as eq
 where (eq->'quantity')::integer >= 150)
order by docket_id desc
--limit 500
```

[image: Analyze Explain]

Comment: You should show text as text, not as images of text.  Especially not images in which some of the important bits have been cut off.

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks for the answer below. PGAdmin won't let you resize columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to directly index jsonb for the existence of a value >= some constant.

You could write a function to summarize the jsonb to the maximum value, index that, then test if this maximum is >= your constant:

```
create function jsonb_max(jsonb, text) returns integer language sql as $$
   select max((e->>$2)::int) from jsonb_array_elements($1) f(e); 
$$ immutable parallel safe;

create index on docket (account_id , docket_type_id, jsonb_max(equipment,'quantity'));

SELECT d.docket_id, d.docket_type_id
FROM docket d
WHERE d.account_id = 557  
   AND (d.docket_type_id = ANY(array[2])) 
   AND jsonb_max(equipment,'quantity')>=150
order by docket_id desc
```

Comment: This took the query down to 364ms, it's definitely answering the question. Thanks for adding that function as well, made the query a lot easier to read and made me rethink how I will continue to work with jsonb data.